# How update provider's data in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a list of a few things and each has its own ID. I want to pass that certain ID to the provider whenever it's clicked. But as of now, when I click on ITEM ONE in the list for the first time, the ID of ITEM ONE is passed to the provider, but when I click again on a different item in the list the ID of that item is not updated in the provider.
I want to know, how can I update the data of the provider every time a new item is clicked.

here are my codes:

- Passing Data

```
onTap: () async {
  Provider.of<providerFile>(context, listen: false).setdataID(DataID);
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPageHome(DataID: DataID)));
},
```

- Provider File

```
String DataID = '';

  void setdataID(String pin) {
    if (DataID.isEmpty) {
      DataID = pin;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Thanks, programmers.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? So we can test it and fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

At second time `DataID` is not anymore empty and therefore not set.

Comment: can you help me with that how I can remove the previous data or empty the provider and then pass new data into it.

Comment: hey dude (@roosi), can you please help me with this? I really need this thing to be done...Please Help!

Comment: Just remove empty check.